# "Universal" control for a property of (roughly) any type?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, reflection

So I'm just wondering, as my research has yielded no results, is there any freely available control (preferably WPF) that is, essentially a "universal" control for a property of any type?

For example, say you are providing a WYSIWYG form constructor, and you want to support multiple value types - strings, bools, ints, datetimes, floats, etc. And of course, Lists of any of those types too... What I'm wondering is, is there already a control out there that, when bound to, will detect the property's type, and then render the appropriate type of control for that type. That is:

For an int, a textbox with up/down buttons and validation that it is an integer
For a datetime, a datetime picker
For a list of datetimes, perhaps a custom control that combines a listbox with a datetime picker, and that lets you add/remove datetimes as needed...

It's relatively simple to write one, I imagine, but difficult to handle all the different types effectively, and of course it couldn't handle more complex types...

Anyone know of anything?

Answer (score 3):

This type of control is usually called a `PropertyGrid`.

Have a look at these controls and see whether they suit your needs:

1. [WPF Property Grid](http://wpg.codeplex.com/)
2. [WPF PropertyGrid Control](http://wpfpropertygrid.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly a perfect solution for you, but Silverlight has a DataForm which when bound to an object of a custom type will generate a form with appropriate controls for the properties. It's not included in WPF, but there is a [WPF port of the Silverlight control](http://wpfdataform.codeplex.com/).

**EDIT**

I miss-read part of your question, making this even less of a solution for you. It still might be of some help though, so I will leave it here.

Answer (score 0):

If you roll your own control, you can provide this functionality fairly easily and incorporate best-of-breed controls for performing specific tasks such as numeric editors and date combos.

We initially searched for an all-inclusive control but, like you, were unable to find one. So we rolled our own with support for more than 15 distinct data rendering types. The entire control, including comments, is only about 1500 lines and that includes a lot of functionality specific to our application, but we were also able to blend in various third-party controls.

The other approach, which we use in a different use case, is to create a common control interface (i.e. set value, get value, are you valid, etc) and then create single-purpose custom controls that implement this interface.

Then to perform mass actions on the controls, it just a matter of cycling through the containers list of controls and, if the control implements our interface, performing the interface action on that control.

This significantly reduces the amount of code that we have to write to perform otherwise standard operations across all controls.